# how to read a file and pick out certain information

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to filter out information from a document and i have to calculate the total revenue for jobs that have  a status of 'A' and  where the status is fully paid (shown in the last column where there is a "0").
I have tried this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
status = open ("paintingJobs.txt" , "r")
for line in status:
  if "A" in line:
    statussplit = line.split(",")
    if (statussplit[5]) == "0":
      print ("...")
```

[image]

Comment: You have to read the text from an image?

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to be working" isn't a question.  Please [edit] your question to include what happened (or didn't happen), and why that was incorrect.  If you received a stack trace, include it in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't stripping the newline character at the end of the line:

```
status = open ("paintingJobs.txt" , "r")
for line in status:
   line = line.rstrip().split(',')
   if line[-2] = 'A' and line[-1] = '0':
      print("...")
```